# JSON.Parse(myJSON) Fails on second feature (Non-Whitespace Character)

Tags: json, geojson, points

The JSON.Parse(myJSON) works if I just use the first feature. If I try to add a comma followed by the second feature I get : Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 204 of the JSON data

It's choking on the comma between the Features I assume.

Here is my code:

var myGeo = '{"type":"Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [-122.331537, 47.673455] },';
myGeo += '"properties":{"NAME": "Donna Lisa","SEX": "F","DATE": "28 Sep 1939","PLAC": "Flotsom-King-Washington-USA"} },';
myGeo += '{"type":"Feature","geometry": { "type":"Point","coordinates": [-122.468178, 48.764218] },';
myGeo += '"properties":{"NAME": "Karen Jetsom","SEX": "F","DATE": "Jan 18 2016","PLAC": "Vernon-Whatcom-Washington-USA"} }';

```
                var myGeo1 = JSON.parse(myGeo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Doh! Two is an array and I had to and square brackets around the whole construct.